# Nifi: Not able to sftp files generated continuously

Tags: sftp, apache-nifi

I am creating a simple nifi pipeline to read file and write the same file to the two different locations. Below is the flow of my pipeline:

1) Read the file from server_1 directory_1

2) copy the file to server_1 directory_2

3) copy the file to server_2 directory_3

A python script is continuously generating csv in server_1 directory_1. I am able to do first and second step, but in third step pipeline is writing only old data. For reading new data I need to empty queue of success_sftp. Below is the screenshot of pipleine:

[image]

In the third case it is showing two behaviour:

1) If no csv file is present in the input directory and I run the flow then it will copy the file coming first(Only first files not the file after that) and success_sftp queue will be full after that.

2)If I have csv file(say 10 file) in input directory and I run the flow then it will copy all the csv files(10 files) to output directory and after that queue will be full. For writing more file I need to empty queue. 
Kindly assist

Comment: What are the errors on PutSFTP?

Comment: No error on PutSftp

Comment: The screenshot shows red in the top right corner of the PutSFTP processor which means there is a bulletin because something was logged at WARN or ERROR level, so there should be an error.